# Android how to get data sent by ble device

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

```
scanResult.getScanRecord()
```

How to get the data sent from the scan record object i am setting data like this

```
String tosendData =  "testdata"; // less than 31 bytes
dataBuilder.addServiceData(Service_UUID, tosendData.getBytes());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private  String getAdviData(ScanRecord scanRecord){

        try {
            return new String( scanRecord.getBytes(), "UTF-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "error";
        }
    }
```

You just parse the array Bytes from the scan record to the data you send.